# Recursive discriminated unions in typescript

Tags: typescript

What would be the best way to model discriminated unions in Typescript where, ideally, one of the fields has a type that references the union itself? To give a simple example

```js
interface Base {
    kind: string;
    someOtherCommonField?: any;
}

interface A extends Base {
    kind: "A";
    children: Base[]; // This ideally would be TheNode[], but I can't forward declare the union (can I?)
}

interface B extends Base {
    kind: "B";
    fieldB: number;
}

type TheNode = A | B;

function makeNode(): TheNode {
    return {kind: "A", children: []};
}

const a = makeNode();

if (a.kind === "A") {
    for (let c of a.children) {
        if (c.kind === "A") {
            c.children // This is an error

            // c needs a cast to A because A#children has type Base[]
            const ca = c as A;
            ca.children // This works but how can I avoid casting?
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**: turns out I was using codesandbox which has a linter by default that marks use before declaration as errors, and since I hadn't touched typescript in a long time I didn't figure out something fishy was going on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can forward declare a union, just as any other `type`

[demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4oN4FgBQyRyA1qACYBcyGYUoA5gNwHE0D2AthAPJgAW0AMJdO7EADFgEADbkA-NTggAni3wBfAgVCRYiFAEFkEAB6QQ5DGkw5WxMpeoAiQ8-VsE-YHKgQQ1AAqggBy7OQQANoAuupa+Drg0PBIaCbm-lY2WMh4hA4ULqjuBPEEYCoADijBEGERyAC8yMYAPmjqBDAAriAIYMDiyJxwJHXhEAAUAJRBoRO59kR+YN1QILmkhciuzgA0yF4+5H4ByDHIGnHa+AjitMhwTcOj4xEznfjAMMiTcAB0jnITUazV200W+SIMHYUF+MggYEOyHYPwBR18-gheTYbG+vwQgIoILBbmxS1xnn+GJO-iYyAA9AzkLV6lFojdKUR4mx4hogA)

Comment: Well that was easy, I didn't even try it ^.^'. Thanks